# "Permission denied (publickey)" only over specific network (SSH key configured)

Tags: git, github, ssh, rsa

I can't clone/pull/push from github only over a specific network:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

My SSH key is well configured on my machine and Github; I can clone/pull/push from my home's network. I tested with other machines connected to the same network and they don't have this problem.

This is the output of `ssh -vT git@github.com`:

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version PaloAltoNetworks_0.2
debug1: no match: PaloAltoNetworks_0.2
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<7680<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: **********
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Julien/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_rsa RSA ********** agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_rsa RSA ********** agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_rsa RSA ********** agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Julien/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No question is a stupid question, being too eager to vote down a question is probably not the healthiest attitude towards newbies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The network is either misconfigured or has a filtering proxy in the way. The remote software version in the output you specified is "PaloAltoNetworks_0.2", which is a filtering appliance provider. GitHub's remote software version should always contain "babeld".

You should contact the network administrator and ask them to remove this filtering.

Comment: Yes, after asking the network administrator, he confirmed there was some filtering causing that.